# Iterate over two strings at the same time

Tags: go

I am just wondering if there is any beautiful way to iterate over two strings at the same time:

```
var ascii_runes = []rune(string_1)
var shifted_runes = []rune(string_2)

for i := 0; i < len(string_1); i++ {
    fmt.Println(string(ascii_runes[i]) + string(shifted_runes[i]))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure IIUC, but for example:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

var (
        ascii   = []rune("string1")
        shifted = []rune("STRING!")
)

func main() {
        for i, v := range ascii {
                fmt.Printf("%c%c\n", v, shifted[i])
        }
}
```

Also here: http://play.golang.org/p/2ruvLFg_qe

---

Output:

```
sS
tT
rR
iI
nN
gG
1!
```

Comment: Didn't know you could declare variables like that - very cool! +1

Comment: Bug alert: `if len(ascii) > len(shifted)`?

Comment: @peterSO: Surely needed if len(ascii) != len(shifted). It's not clear to me if that's the domain of the OP or not. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var runes_1, runes_2 = []rune("string_1"), []rune("string_2")
    for i := 0; i < len(runes_1) && i < len(runes_2); i++ {
        fmt.Println(string(runes_1[i]) + string(runes_2[i]))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ss
tt
rr
ii
nn
gg
__
12
```

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly beautiful, but an efficient way is to use [strings.NewReader](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader) and its [ReadRune](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Reader.ReadRune) method.

```
func Less(s1, s2 string) bool {
  rdr1 := strings.NewReader(s1)
  rdr2 := strings.NewReader(s2)
  for {
    rune1, _, err1 := rdr1.ReadRune()
    rune2, _, err2 := rdr2.ReadRune()
    if err2 == io.EOF { return false }
    if err1 == io.EOF { return true }
    if rune1 != rune2 { return rune1 < rune2 }
  }
}
```